# Ruby on Rails CMS with multiple languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, content-management-system

I'm currently working on a project with Ruby on Rails. I need a CMS and multiple language integration. As of right now, I need the site to be shown only in English and Spanish.

Is there any Ruby on Rails CMS that handles this easily?
If not, which Ruby on Rails CMS would you recommend that allows this to be implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, use [Refinery](http://refinerycms.com/), it's straight.

---

In spite of @tadman answers success, beware of community support:

- Sofa: 390 followers on github
- Refinery: 1728.

There is a sign here, even if there is no truth...

Comment: @tadman has more stackoverflow points so he must be more correct than you... But you have more medals... hmmmm.

Comment: You've got a point, I will evaluate both options though.

Answer (score 5):

An associate of mine has produced [Comfortable Mexican Sofa](http://jeffpoulton.com/2011/09/managing-static-content-in-a-ruby-on-rails-application/) which supports multiple versions of pages in multiple languages. It compares well to Refinery in terms of features.

Most systems will do it if you can have different layouts for each language.

Comment: And it just happen to have both English and Spanish!

Comment: I think I'll evaluate both Comfortable Mexican Sofa and Refinery for a while

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use [RefineryCMS](http://refinerycms.com/), with the gem [refinerycms-i18n](https://github.com/parndt/refinerycms-i18n), which will offer you the needed internationalization options.

Other cms alternatives:

- [browsercms](http://www.browsercms.org/): this looks promising, but I have no idea what the support for internationalization is
- [radiantcms](http://radiantcms.org): the oldest cms, awesome community, unfortunately not based on rails 3; but maybe if you want a pure cms that does not matter.
- [Locomotive CMS](http://www.locomotivecms.com/): has internationalization out of the box, looks clean and slick, very promising, will have to investigate this